# getting zero objects from BackendlessUser getProperty()

Tags: java, android, backendless

I've setup Backendless app, with `User` table having row name `posts`, which is data object relationship between `User` and `Post` tables, data relation is 1 to many. When I try to retrieve it using `BackendlessUser.getProperty("key")`, it returns zero objects. Once it even returned `HashMap`. I used the way mentioned in the  the [docs](https://backendless.com/documentation/users/android/users_user_properties.htm), but get null because the size of the `Object[]` is zero. I have data in that row for sure, wrote `<uses-permission>` for internet.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BackendlessUser user = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Backendless.initApp(this, "app_id", "android_key", "v1");

        Backendless.UserService.login("username", "password", new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser response) {
                user = response;
                doStuff();
            }
            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                Log.e("Error logging in", "message: " + fault.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    //important
    private void doStuff() {
        Object[] postObjectArray = (Object[]) user.getProperty("posts");

        Post[] posts = null;

        if (postObjectArray != null && postObjectArray.length > 0)
            posts = (Post[])postObjectArray;

        if (posts == null)
        {
            Log.d("Problems", "posts is null");
        }
    }
}
```

`Post` class:

```
public class Post extends Object{

    private BackendlessUser user;
    private String file;
    private String message;
    private String objectId;

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(BackendlessUser user, String file, String message) {
        this.user = user;
        this.file = file;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public BackendlessUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(BackendlessUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that checkbox "autoload", which loads all values of one to many relationships to which checkbox corresponds when the owning table was loaded, wasn't checked. Thus, `user.getProperty("posts")` was always returning null. But it should be noted that if the row is data object relationship, it returns `HashMap<String, Object>`, so  Post needs to have constructor which accepts `HashMap<String, Object>`:

```
public Post(HashMap hashMap)
{
    this.hashMap = hashMap;
    property1 = (String)hashMap.get("property1");
    /*other properties*/
}
```

If there is no values, it will return an `Object`, which **is not** castable to any other type, so the way used in the docs **must be** applied in order to fix edge cases.

**EDIT:**

It's useful to [map data table to class](https://backendless.com/feature-123-custom-mapping-between-data-tables-and-client-classes/) before making any calls to Backendless. That way, it is possible to eliminate all work with `HashMap` and directly get desired type. Despite that, if you're retrieving data through `Backendless.Persistence` you can specify it as argument.